# Bazaar version control - Multiple repositories / sub modules possible?

Tags: version-control, bazaar, bazaar-plugins

Is it possible to have multiple repositories / sub modules?

If so, how?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to nesting separate repositories within your main repository like SVN externals, see the bzr externals plugin:

https://launchpad.net/bzr-externals